# Use Adwaita Dark for Libre Office and possibly other apps too?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk3

I would like to know how to force some apps to use the Adwaita dark theme. I noticed by default that the movie player and photo viewer apps in gnome shell use Adwaita Dark while most other apps use the Light variant. I would really like to set Libre Office to use Dark instead of Light. How would I go about doing this?

I found the site below, but the instructions seem a bit outdated and they do not work for GTK3. 
http://urukrama.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/setting-a-custom-gtk-theme-for-specific-applications/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure how to do this, but I believe you need an "application.css" file within the theme folder (for example there is one for Nautilus in some themes), with the theme description.

LibreOffice will not work with that theme however because it doesn't yet support GTK+ 3.x correctly.

Comment: I thought that Libre Office did get proper GTK+ 3.x support with the latest version? Either way, I still have other apps I would like to do this to as well. I went through all the .css files in the theme dir and found nothing that appeared relevant. I even checked the launch command for totem through the menu editor to see if it has any parameters, no luck. I know the answer has to be simple, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: @Relik: I had previously asked somewhere about this theme and was told that it is in the theme directory. I don't know how it is activated though, it might be that the application has to activate it from within itself.